# How to put many objects in a scroll view entry in android?

Tags: android, list, object

I want to create a database where I get some data like name, two boolean represented by a toggle button and a checklist and list everything in a scroll view like in figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyEP2.jpg). Also I want to add a "delete" and "update" button in the same entry of the scrollview.

I've seen you can put a horizontal LinearLayout in the vertical Linearlayour which is created in the `ScrollView`, in this way I can put the text and buttons in the same line. But when I do that I can't add another line for the toggle and checkbox information and also I can't put a common background to the whole entry.

Could anyone give me a hint of how should I address this problem? I've tried to solve it in the xml main layout just to get an idea to then translate it to the code, but I can't get it to work.

[image]

Comment: Since the views are repeating, I believe it makes more sense that you put your data in a [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).

Comment: or `RecyclerView` => https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add another LinearLayout as a container for every list item:

```
- ScrollView
    - LinearLayout (vertical) -> List container
        - LinearLayout (vertical) -> Item container
            - LinearLayout (horizontal)
                ...some elements....
            - End of LinearLayout (horizontal)
            - LinearLayout (horizontal)
                ...more elements....
            - End of LinearLayout (horizontal)
        - End of LinearLayout (vertical) -> Item container
        ...More item containers...
    - End of LinearLayout (vertical) -> List container
- End of ScrollView
```

This is not the exact layout as in your image but you should solve it following this pattern.

Despite this, as others said in their comments this can be achieved in a more efficient way using a ListView or better a RecyclerView.

I can't show you a real example right now, I will do it later if you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I,ve to respond as a comment or as an answer. I've followed @Alberto Méndez's answer and changed to lists as comments said and I think I got the solution, I still need to work on making look better but the structure is what I was trying to do:
auxiliary_list.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_name_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title_entry"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox_list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Checkbox"
                    android:clickable="false" />
                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch_button_list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textOff="Text off"
                    android:textOn="Text on"
                    android:clickable="false" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/update_entry_list"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:height="10dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/delete_entry_list"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:height="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/screen_padding"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/background_gradient">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/title"
    android:id="@+id/manage_exercises_title"
    android:text="@string/title"/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/content_spacing" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</ListView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java code filled with an example:

```
package com.example.nck.routine_tracker;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Arrays;
/**
 * Created by nck on 14/10/16.
 */
public class MainJavaFile extends Activity{
ListView list;
String [] text = new String[20];
boolean [] option1 = new boolean[20];;
boolean [] option2 = new boolean[20];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_xml);
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
        text[i]=""+ i + "º Entry";
    }
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_1);
    list.setAdapter(new listAdapter(text,option1,option2, this.getBaseContext()));
    Toast.makeText(this, text[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
class listAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] text;
    boolean[] option1, option2;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public listAdapter() {
        text = null;
        option1 = null;
        option2 = null;
    }

    public listAdapter(String[] text, boolean[] option1, boolean[] option2, Context context) {
        this.text = text;
        this.option1 = option1;
        this.option2 = option2;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return text.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.auxiliary_list, parent, false);
        TextView Text;
        CheckBox Option1;
        Switch Option2;
        Text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.main_name_list);
        Option1 = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_list);
        Option2 = (Switch) row.findViewById(R.id.switch_button_list);
        Text.setText(text[position]);
        Option1.setChecked(option1[position]);
        Option2.setEnabled(option2[position]);
        return (row);
    }
}
```

And the solution:
[image: Solution]

Comment: Glad to hear you got it